# Cant add data into my database on last query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Why I cant add the value on the last query (`EventEndDate`)

```
string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO eventreservation(EventID,CustomerName,CustomerIC," +
                      "CustomerPhone,StartDate,EndDate) VALUES('" + txtEventID.Text + "'," +
                      "'" + txtCustomerName.Text + "','" + txtCustomerIC.Text + "','" + 
                      txtCustomerPhone.Text + "','" + EventStartDate.Text + "'," + 
                      EventEndDate.Text + ")";
```

Comment: Never concat strings to make SQL, use parameters, never store dates as text and please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: please clarify your question. Tell here what do you need.

Comment: my last query doesn't insert the value [EventEndDate] and it give me 0000-00-00 on the database

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection may be of use.

Comment: Ty for helping, this help me a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed a single quote `'` in your last entry:

```
," + EventEndDate.Text + "
```

That should be:

```
,'" + EventEndDate.Text + "'
```

However this kind of string concatenation is open for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Try [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) instead. Something like this:

```
string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO eventreservation(EventID,CustomerName,CustomerIC," +
                             "CustomerPhone,StartDate,EndDate)VALUES(@EventID,@CustomerName," +
                             "CustomerIC,@CustomerPhone,@StartDate,@EndDate)";
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@EventID,txtEventID.Text);
//Other parameters
```

Although specify the type directly and use the `Value` property is more better than `AddWithValue`:

```
insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@EventID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEventID.Text;
```

Comment: already try it. the value still 0000-00-00 in the database

Comment: @GrimoriaGrimore Try the parameterized queries version of the answer. It should works.

Comment: @GrimoriaGrimore Also it seems that `EndDate` is of type `DateTime`, if so you need to convert it to `DateTime` like this: `Convert.ToDateTime(EventEndDate.Text)`

Comment: @GrimoriaGrimore Or specify the type directly and use the `Value` property. Check my updated answer.

Comment: but the EventStartDate query working fine, it have same type with EventEndDate

Comment: I follow the tutorials based on this video [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTvAfgOPlT4)

Comment: `the value still 0000-00-00 in the database` Can you update your post with a screenshot of that value, as well as the types of the database columns? _I am surprised that `0000-00-00` is there since SQL Server doesn't support Year 0 in dates._

Comment: found the problem, my SQL seem to have problem. reinstall it...